# WordPress showing error message while redirecting

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin where a login and registration page exist ( custom page using shortcode ).

So here, I am redirecting the user if **logged in user** is going to **www.mysite.com/login** page as it's the **login page.**

But it's showing following error when I ( as a user) go to that login page.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\laragon\www\wp\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:287) in
>   C:\laragon\www\wp\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1265
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\laragon\www\wp\wp-includes\class.wp-styles.php:287) in
>   C:\laragon\www\wp\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1268

**The Code:**

```
final class ShibbirDirectoryListing
{ 

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (is_null(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
            self::$instance->setup();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function setup()
    {
        $this->check_environment();
        $this->define_constant();
        $this->includes();
        $this->init_hooks();
        $this->plugin_init();
        do_action('shibbir_directory_listing_loaded');
    } 


    /**
     * Include required core files which is used in both admin and frontend
     */
    public function includes()
    {
        // Includes only in frontend
        if( $this->is_request( 'frontend' ) ) {
            include_once SDL_INCLUDES . '/class-shortcodes.php';
            include_once SDL_INCLUDES . '/class-frontend.php';            
        }        
    }   
}

/**
 * Get the instance of the plugin 
 */
function shibbir_directory_listing()
{
    return ShibbirDirectoryListing::instance();
}

// Let's start the Engine
shibbir_directory_listing();
```

**class-frontend.php file**

```
<?php
namespace Shibbir\ShibbirDirectoryListing;

class ShortCode {
    public function __construct() {                
        add_shortcode( 'sdl_login', array( $this, 'render_login_form' ) );
        add_shortcode( 'sdl_registration', array( $this, 'render_registration_form' ) );
    }    

    public function render_login_form() {        
        if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            wp_redirect( site_url( '/') );
            exit;
        }
        include SDL_TEMPLATES_DIR . '/login-form.php';        
    }
}
```

From this line

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
     wp_redirect( site_url( '/') );
     exit;
 }
```

those error messages are showing :(

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`wp_redirect()` redirects via HTTP headers.  It won't work after page output (headers) are sent. So you can't just use this function in a shortcode.  `wp_redirect` should be used typically before `init`

In a shortcode, you could do this:

```
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $output = '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "'.site_url().'";</script>'
        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm. Good Idea though.